# Recommended option to add item list from predefined list

Tags: forms, layout, lists

I need to build an interface where the user will dynamically build an item from a pre defined list of items, like the following example:

```
Personnel Team

Name: Peter Gabriel
Description: Sr. IT Analyst

Certifications:                                 [+ Add new Certification]

Name                    |     Description                               
CISCO Certification     | CISCO ASA Test Exam 001
Palo Alto Certification | Palo Alto Test Exam 001
```

The certification list is build from a pre defined list:

```
    Available Certifications -----------------------------
    CISCO Certification       | CISCO ASA Test Exam 001
    Palo Alto Certification   | Palo Alto Test Exam 001
    Check Point Certification | Check Point Test Exam 001
    VM SERIES Certification   | VM SERIES Test Exam 001
    Microsoft Certification   | Microsoft Test Exam 001
    Java Certification        | Java Test Exam 001
```

Naturally, when opening the `[Add New Certification]`, those already inserted are not shown.

What would be the receommended way to build that intereface, considering the user must be able to add, remove and reorder the certification list (order is important).

Comment: What's the input method? Mouse? Touch? Stylo? Which devices you have to support? Is it a web, a desktop or a mobile application? Any combination of the above?

Comment: Web support for computers on web application. Mouse support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about an autocomplete list that allows the user to start typing a term, and then shows suggested certifications? If the user enters a new term that isn't pre-existing, this could be added to the master list of terms.

[image]

The order could be handled by letting the user see a draggable handle icon next to their list. An edit/remove link can show next to each term.

[image]